# Zend Framework SQL query Update not working

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I've got this query, from what I've found of examples here and in the docs this should work, but the script is saying no.. needs array not string. Do I have to do something like

```
$db = $this->db = Zend_Registry::getinstance()->dbAdapter;
$db->select()->from('offer_term')->where('term_id = '.$entry[$i]);
$db->update('status = 0');
```

with the above I get an error about it not taking a string it needs to be an array.

with the below my whole script breaks. So, I'm kinda new to Zend, anyone care to elaborate as to what I am doing wrong?

```
$db = $this->db = Zend_Registry::getinstance()->dbAdapter;
$db->select()->from('offer_term')->where('term_id = ?',array($entry[$i]));
$db->update('status = ?', array('0'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the Zend Framework documentation of `update()` [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.write.update).

The method's signature is:

```
$db->update($table, $data, $where);
```

This means that you'll have to let the adapter know which table you are updating, as well as which row(s) from that table.

You should probably rewrite your code to:

```
$db->update(
    'offer_term', 
    array('status' => 0), 
    array('term_id = ?' => $entry[$i])
);
```

This will translate into:

```
UPDATE offer_term
SET status = 0
WHERE term_id = <myEntry>
```